# ADAL 3 Windown 8.1 App Nuget Update failing

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8.1, nuget-package, adal

My Windows 8.1 app is using ADAL 2.11.10918.1222 without a problem. I wanted to update to ADAL 3.x using NuGet package manager but it is failing with this error:

> Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory'

I compared the *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.3.10.305231913* package folder with the older version and realized in ADAL 3 package all libraries have **Dll** extension whicle in ADAL 2 libraries that I use are **winmd** files.
Has anyone tried to upgrade ADAL for Windows 8.1 solution? Is ADAL 3 supported for Windows 8.1 Apps? I am using Visual Studio 2015 with all updates installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADAL v3 does not support Winmd anymore. It only provides class library now.

Comment: you mean there is no way to update to ADAL 3 for windows 8.1 apps?

Comment: I just tried creating a simple windows 8.1 app (not win runtime) in c# and I was able to add Adalv3 as a dependency. If your app is in c# as well then you should be able to use the dll

Comment: My app is in Javascript, any idea about that?

Comment: Sorry that is not supported. You can stay with adal v2 as it still works with AAD.